# $\lim_n nr^n$ if $|r| < 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

In an exercise I'm asked to study the limit of the following sequence:

$$(nr^n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$$

I'm aware of the following:

- If $|r|>1$ then the sequence diverges if $r$ is positive, or it has no limit if $r$ is negative.
- If $r=1$ then it also diverges
- If $r = -1$ then it has no limit

But I'm not being able to find out what the limit is when $|r| < 1$. I know that if that's the case then $\lim_n r^n = 0$, but I don't know how to do this for this sequence.

Comment: Which series are you writing about?

Comment: The sequence $(nr^n)_n$ @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Then why did you write “series”? That's quite confusing.

Comment: My bad. Already corrected it @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Ratio or root test works.

Comment: Hint. Differentiate   a geometric series (whose sum you know) term by term. Then you're close to what you want.

Comment: You can find similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431980/prove-displaystyle-lim-n-to-inftynbn-0) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988459/show-that-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-inftynbn-0-for-0b1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $0 < r < 1$ and note that
$$n=n(r + (1-r))^n=nr^n\left(1 + \frac{1-r}{r}\right)^n.$$

Using the binomial theorem, we have

$$nr^n = \frac{n}{\left(1 + \frac{1-r}{r}\right)^n} < \frac{n}{1 + n\frac{(1 - r)}{r} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\frac{(1-r)^2}{r^2} }.$$

Therefore, $nr^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

From the ratio test you know that $n r^n \to 0$ if:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac {(n + 1)r^{n + 1}} {n r^n}\right| < 1$$

Alternatively you can use the root test, or consider the derivative of $(1 - x)^{-1} = \sum x^n$ as suggested by Ethan Bolker in the comments, though this is pretty non-trivial if you're to justify it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Take

$$n_0>\frac r{1-r}$$

so that for all $n\ge n_0$
$$\frac{n+1}nr\le s<1.$$

Then by telescoping on $n_0+1,n_0+2,\cdots n_0+n$,

$$\frac{n_0+n}{n_0}r^n<s^n$$ and $$nr^n<n_0s^n.$$